# Is Nougat 'Emergency Info' synched?

Tags: sync, google-account, 7.0-nougat

I was reading on some new Nougat features just now, and it mentioned a new feature, that lets you make emergency information (blood type, allergies, emergency contacts, etc) available on the lock screen.

Got me wondering though, will that information sync on your Google account? If you enter that info on one Nougat (and later, theoretically) device, will it also be entered on other Nougat devices on the same account? Or will you have to enter it on each new phone/device going forward?